# Testing validations in model using RSpec with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec, model

I'm super new to testing my app using RSpec and I'm trying to test the validation of a comment without a user and keep getting syntax errors.
Here is the comment model code.

```ruby
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

  scope :rating_desc, -> { order(rating: :desc) }

  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :product, presence: true
  validates :rating, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  after_create_commit { CommentUpdateJob.perform_later(self, user) }
end
```

and here is the comment spec:

```ruby
require 'rails_helper'

describe Comment do 
  before do 
    @product = Product.create!(name: "race bike", description: "fast race bike")
        @user = User.create!(email: "jerryhoglen@me.com", password: "Maggie1!")
        @product.comments.create!(rating: 1, user: @user, body: "Awful bike!")
  end

  it "is invalid without a user"
   expect(build(:comment, user:nil)).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: /Users/jerryhoglen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load': /Users/jerryhoglen/Desktop/nameofapp/spec/models/comment_spec.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError) @ZhongZheng

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing here is good - building objects and using the `be_valid` matcher. But if you use [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) there's a one-liner to test a model validation:

```
describe Comment do
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of :user }
end
```

You can do this for other validations such as uniqueness, numericality, etc, though you'd have to look up the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you missed a `do`, do it like:

```ruby
it "is invalid without a user" do
  expect(build(:comment, user: nil)).to_not be_valid
end
```

But that's not a very clear test when it fails, I suggest you check the actual expected validation error.
That's what it may look like:

```
expect(ValidatingWidget.new.errors_on(:name)).to include("can't be blank")
expect(ValidatingWidget.new(:name => "liquid nitrogen")).to have(0).errors_on(:name)
```

See [rspec-rails errors_on @ relishapp](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/model-specs/errors-on)

Comment: .F..

Failures:

  1) Comment is invalid without a user
     Failure/Error: expect(build(:comment, user:nil)).to_not be_valid

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `build' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Comment:0x007f9e930b3bd0>
     # ./spec/models/comment_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.25242 seconds (files took 2.57 seconds to load)
9 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/comment_spec.rb:11 # Comment is invalid without a user @zhongzheng

Comment: do you have FactoryGirl installed? try `FactoryGirl.build(:comment, user:nil)`

Comment: 1) Comment is invalid without a user
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.build(:comment, user:nil)

     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: comment @zhongZheng

Comment: You need to define factory for comment model.